Missing GCC Plugins in meta-toolchain
I am encountering an error while compiling an out-of-tree kernel module/driver.
I am trying to build the driver for my kernel version 6.1.46 using a Yocto-generated toolchain. During compilation of the driver, I get the following error:
cc1: error: cannot load plugin ./scripts/gcc-plugins/arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.so: ./scripts/gcc-plugins/arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN8opt_pass14set_pass_paramEjb

To resolve this, I attempted to modify meta/recipes-devtools/ by enabling the GCC plugin with the following change:
Edited gcc-11.4.inc to include --enable-plugin.
However, the issue persists, and I was not successful.
Is there a proper method to include GCC plugins in the generated toolchain binaries, or am I approaching this incorrectly? Any guidance would be appreciated.
